# What is $i^i$?Imaginary, Real, HyperComplex?

Tags: complex-numbers

What is $ i^i$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit.
Apparently wolfram alpha and google give:
$$i^i\approx0.207879576=e^{-\pi/2}$$
But how?

---

Maybe let me try:
$$x=i^i\implies x=\exp(i\ln i)$$
$$x=\exp\left(i\left(i-\frac{i^2}2+\frac{i^3}3-\frac{i^4}4+\cdots\right)\right)$$
$$x=\exp\left(i\left(i-\frac{1}2-\frac{i}3+\frac{1}4+\cdots\right)\right)$$
$$x=\exp\left(-1-\frac{i}2+\frac{1}3+\frac{i}4+\cdots\right)=^{\text {?}}\exp(-\pi/2)$$

Comment: Write $i$ in polar form, $i=e^{i\pi/2}$, so $i^i=\big(e^{i\pi/2}\big)^i$.

Comment: $\log(i)=\frac{i \pi }{2}$ gives the result $i^i=e^{-\pi /2}$

Comment: The notation $i^i$ is illegal, as explained in several recent posts on the site. So the answer to the question in the title is "Nonexistent".

Comment: @Did can you specify some? or even one? Soory I didn't paid so attention to all posts. Also it would be better if you can, not necessarily explain, WHY?

Comment: An easy argument: $i=e^{5i\pi/2}$ "hence" $i^i=e^{-5\pi/2}$. And $i^i=e^{-9\pi/2}$. And... // The flaw in the approach in your post is that it uses the series expansion of the logarithm at a point where it *diverges* absolutely.

Comment: @Did: When did "depends on choice of branch cut" become "is illegal"? Have we criminalized the complex logarithm as well?

Comment: @Rahul Sorry, if you decide to come back to a more civilized mode of communication, I might explain to you the problem with this notation (if ever my last comment, say, is not enough). But until then...

Comment: @Did: No, I understand what you're saying in your last comment, I think, but it sure seems like exactly the same argument would eliminate notation like $x^{1/2}$ even for positive reals as well. (Eliminate, cause to be illegal (your words), criminalize (= "make illegal", my paraphrase), same thing.)

Comment: @Rahul This is a strawman argument. Mentioning the (serious) problem with $z^{1/2}$ for $z$ complex is not the same as saying there would be a problem with $x^{1/2}$ for $x$ real nonnegative (there is none).

Comment: I remember when my teacher said this was impossible, if it weren't for $cis \theta$ , I wouldn't ever have proved him wrong.

Comment: @Nick Yes... That such a banal piece of maths is facing a furious opposition, repeatedly, and from several math.se users, is something worthy of an explanation. This might be related to some specific educational systems deliberately neglecting the point (and even, misleading students about it). Do you have any informed view about this?

Comment: @Did: This is the Mathematician vs Math-teacher phenomenon. There's just too far a gap between the two that the latter doesn't even need to know how to count if he knows the answers to the questions in the textbook. So, that's what I think the primary cause is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $i = \exp\left(\frac{\pi}{2} i\right)$, we have

$i^i = \exp\left(\frac{\pi}{2} i\cdot i\right) = e^{-\pi / 2}$

as desired.

Comment: Does ?$i=\exp(i\pi/2)=\cos(\pi/2)+i\sin(\pi/2)=i$, then $i^i$ would be $e^{i\ln i}=e^{i\ln(e^{i\pi/2})}=e^{i.i\pi/2}=e^{-\pi/2}$?

Comment: @Aditya yes. ${} {}$

Comment: @Aditya Yes, that's right, but note that, as your computation makes explicit this computation depends implicitly on a choice of branch cut for $\ln$; more explicitly, to write $i^i = e^{-\pi/2}$, we must use a branch cut for which $\ln i = \frac{\pi}{2} i$, and the "usual" does just find. If this sort of situation bothers you, just write your expression in the form $\exp w$ from the outside.